# Where does Firefox Saves Add-on files on Local Storage?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

It might be hard to relate to but VSCode (a code editor) saves all the installed extensions locally in `Users` folder with the name of `.vscode/extensions`. Any one can copy the folder and paste it on other system with VSCode installed to have the same extensions (on Windows).

Is there such a folder for Firefox browser add-ons?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the path on windows. `[User]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox`. There should be three folders each having two extensions related folders where all the extensions are saved.